# Minimum heap and heap sorting Algorithm in c

Tags: c, algorithm, heap, minimum, heapsort

Hello I got stuck in coding arithmetic operation. Please help me to find the right numbers.. I used the number: 22,17,49,55,18,69,24,30,20,21.

For the minimizing heap 
I've got: 17,18,24,20,21,69,49,30,55,22

Also for the sorting the heap, 
I've got: 69,55,49,30,24,22,21,20,18,17

All by handwork.
and the output from the code gives me the wrong number, I borrowed codes and using it. (thank you for sharing guys)

Please help me with this guys.. I've been learning java and just got into the college and learning C, as a supper beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{ 
  int heap[10], no, i, j, c, root, temp;
  printf("\n Enter no of elements :");
  scanf_s("%d", &no);
  printf("\n Enter the input number : ");
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
    scanf_s("%d", &heap[i]);
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  printf("\n Your input number is : ");
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
    printf("%d\t ", heap[i]);
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  for (i = 1; i < no; i++)
  {
    c = i;
    do
    {
      root = (c - 1) / 2;
      if (heap[root] < heap[c])   
      {
        temp = heap[root];
        heap[root] = heap[c];
        heap[c] = temp;
      }
      c = root;
    } while (c != 0);
  }
  printf("\n The makeHeap number is : ");
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
    printf("%d\t ", heap[i]);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  for (j = no - 1; j >= 0; j--)
  {
    temp = heap[0];
    heap[0] = heap[j];    
    heap[j] = temp;
    root = 0;
    do
    {
      c = 2 * root + 1;    
      if ((heap[c] < heap[c + 1]) && c < j - 1)
        c++;
      if (heap[root] < heap[c] && c < j)   
      {
        temp = heap[root];
        heap[root] = heap[c];
        heap[c] = temp;
      }
      root = c;
    } while (c < j);
  }
  printf("\n The sorted number is : ");
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
    printf("%d\t", heap[i]);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  printf("\n ");
  printf("\n ");
}
```

Comment: if I compile and execute the sorted numbers are ok `The sorted number is : 17 18 20 21 22 24 30 49 55 69`. What do you expected for the _makeHeap_, I get `The makeHeap number is : 69  55  49  30  22  18  24  17`. Note : `int main() ...`

Comment: With `-fsanitize=address`: heap.c:44:16: runtime error: index 13 out of bounds for type 'int [10]'

Comment: Line 44 is `if ((heap[c] < heap[c + 1]) && c < j - 1)`, i.e. you never check if `c` is still within the heap.

Comment: `learning C` && `I borrowed codes` questionable approach, more so given the commentation quality of the code presented. Note the [conventional procedure to build a min heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) "is linear". To add, as [Antti Haapala comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206579/minimum-heap-and-heap-sorting-algorithm-in-c#comment97150814_55206579) the order of conditions in "extract-min" is wrong: *first* check if index is valid, only then use it to index the array.

Comment: Also, functions. They're good idea also in C. Use 'em.